# Parse a column that is an json object

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, apache-spark, databricks

I would like to query this column that is a JSON object.

```
|  x  |     y     |                        z                  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  | first      | {"first_name":["Pat","Amy T."],"last_name":["Liman","Pedano"],"updated_at":["1989-11-30T19:00:00.000-05:00","2018-10-11T12:45:44.674-04:00"]}    |
|  2  | second    | {"first_name":["Elli","Ala"],"last_name":["Sheppard","Mcgrial"],"updated_at":["2019-03-16T11:15:25.714-04:00","2019-05-21T11:29:00.684-04:00"]}   |
```

where z is a json object.

I tried

```
SELECT x, y, t1.first_name, t1.last_name, t1.updated_at
FROM versions_table v
    LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(v.z, 'first_name', 'last_name', 'updated_at') t1 
    as `first_name`, `last_name`, `updated_at`
where first_name is not null;
```

but I'm getting an json array. What would be the best approach to change the date format for

the  output to be like this `2019-01-03`.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using postgresql or mysql?  They're different databases

Comment: No clear if the column type is a datetime format or string since it does have the T in there but: try select cast(updated_at as date) FROM ....

Comment: I'm doing this query in databricks, which is  Spark SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date string is in "combined timestamp" format. To my understanding, you're just trying to cast that string into a date type.

**PostgreSQL**

The following example works and will cast your string into the date you want:

```sql
SELECT '2018-10-11T12:45:44.674-04:00'::date
```

You can learn some more about casting in [this tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cast/). `::` is the cast operator.

Another option would be to use the [to_date function or similar](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-formatting.html):

```sql
SELECT to_date('2018-10-11T12:45:44.674-04:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

**MySQL**

In MySQL you can use the [DATE function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

```
SELECT DATE('2018-10-11T12:45:44.674-04:00')
```

Comment: @MarianaLungu Is the problem that you don't know how to select the string from the JSON object?

Comment: I have this column ```updated_at``` and I need to change the format from  ``` ["2019-01-05T17:28:32.506-05:00","2019-06-15T13:22:02.625-04:00"] ``` .     to ``` 2019-01-05, 2019-06-15 ``` but because its a json array i'm not sure how I can accomplish that!

Comment: Perhaps the postgres function `json_array_elements` or `json_array_elements_text` and similar would help you? This function expands a JSON array into a result set. [Here's the docs on that](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html). Does that help at all?